# Obtaining a H2A visa outside of own country?

Tags: visa

I'm from the UK. currently in the states on H2A visa and I am travelling to new Zealand on a working holiday visa for a few months.

My question is, as a British citizen will I be able to visit an American embassy in new Zealand to get my H2A visa for 2020 or will I have to travel back to England?

Thanks, Ryan

Comment: I know that H-1B workers often get their visas replaced in Canada or Mexico despite not being from those countries, so I suspect that you should have no trouble getting it done in New Zealand.  I also know that in general, it's possible to get a US visa in any country, though individuals can be constrained to their own country of citizenship if they've overstayed a visa in the past ([8 USC 1202(g)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1202#g)).  I do not know whether these general priciples apply to H-2A visas, however, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.